# What are the "sleepimage" and "swapfile" documents?

Tags: sleep-wake, storage, macos, virtual-memory

I was using [Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com) and found a file called `sleepimage` in `/private/var/vm/` It takes up 4 GB! I also found numerous other files in the same folder called `swapfile0` `swapfile1`, etc. What are they and are they safe to delete so I can free up space? (almost 10 GB)

Comment: I expect the "swapfiles" are for memory swapping, and the "sleepimage" is the saved state when the computer enters hibernation.

Comment: A very simple google search could answer this…

Comment: It's not helpful to complain about a question that you find trivial via the medium of a comment that everyone else will also find trivial.  I note there are no downvotes on the question, and that is the preferred method of providing such input.

Comment: Last comment ref @XAleXOwnZX

Comment: @Alexander I did a simple google search and found this.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`swapfile0`, `swapfile1` and so on are swap files. You can sort of think of them like "backup" RAM. When your computer doesn't have enough RAM to accomodate the memory requests of all your programs (which is almost always, this is normal), it uses these files to "write out" part of what it had in RAM.

The `sleepimage` has a very similar use, except it's used only when your Mac hibernates/wakes up.

Deleting any of the `swapfile*` files is likely to mess up your system, but you can safely delete `sleepimage`. However, it's kind of pointless, it will probably be recreated the next time you put your computer to hibernation. If you *really* want to delete it, you'd have to use `sudo rm`, since `root` owns the file.

Finally, it's normal for the `sleepimage` to take up to 4 GB; it will usually take the same space as your RAM.

**EDIT** You can delete `/var/vm/sleepimage` safely, but it will be recreated when you put the Mac to sleep. If you `run sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 0; sudo rm /var/vm/sleepimage`, the Mac will use a normal sleep mode (like desktop Macs by default) and it won't recreate `/var/vm/sleepimage`. See [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50235/what-i-can-delete-from-private-var-vm) post with more information.

Comment: On Macs, a "hibernation" state is only ever used on laptops when the battery dies. I believe a typical system sleep will not write the contents of RAM to disk. (Can anyone confirm this?)

Comment: @NReilingh: I believe so, yes.

Comment: @NReilingh Laptops both keep the memory powered but also write its contents to the sleepimage by default. See `man pmset` and [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51725/).

Answer (score 3):

Those are part of the virtual memory system: `swapfile*` contains literally swap data, which is memory content that has been pushed out to disk.

The `sleepimage` is used for suspend and resume support; when the system hibernates, that is where the memory data is stored.

Deleting either would cause significant problems: sleepimage is the same size as RAM, and would need to be recreated to sleep; the swap files are memory that is in use, and would cause serious problems to delete.

If you use less swap, the system will automatically deallocate those files, though, and free that disk space.

Comment: `sleepimage` is not part of the *virtual* memory system. `sleepimage` relates to power management and *physical* memory.

Answer (score 2):

I just deleted my sleepimage and everything works fine, and to permanently prevent it from reappearing, follow the steps outlined in the comments of [this article](http://osxdaily.com/2010/10/11/sleepimage-mac/)

*Summary…*

- Can I safely delete sleepimage from my Mac?
- Yes, you can remove sleepimage and it will just be created again automatically the next time your Mac is put to sleep. To delete sleepimage, type the following command into the Terminal:

  sudo rm /private/var/vm/sleepimage

You’ll be asked for the administrator password to gain access to remove the file, this is normal.

The sleepimage file is only needed for the safe-sleep function where your data is saved to the HDD before sleeping, if you want to permanently reclaim this disk space you can do so using the following commands in a terminal window.
This will revert your computer to the older sleep method, which will sleep faster and wake faster but does keep your data in memory during the sleep period.

to check which mode is active

```
pmset -g | grep hibernatemode
```

to change mode 0= old style sleep 3= new (save to disk style)

```
sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 0
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please summarize the content of the article you are linking. The answer should be enough for solving the problem. Then you can provide additional information by using links.

Comment: I inlined the salient parts from the link.