# 20Gb of sleepimage OSX Mavericks

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, startup

I realized that I'm always I receive a message informing that my startup disk is almost full. So I used the "Disk Inventory" App to know what was happening.

My sleepimage was bigger than 20Gb, I read that one of the Mavericks OS features was the little size of sleepimage.

Could I delete the file? If I do, the sleepimage will work normally?

Comment: DO you need sleepimage? it speeds up wakeup from hibernation (but not sleep) see http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/50272/237

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the sleepimage should match the amount of RAM installed in your computer. does your computer have 20GB of RAM?

if not I suppose something is wrong and maybe it could be fixed by deleting the sleepimage and letting it be recreated when needed next. You may want to verify your disk with disk utility to check for FS damage.

to delete the image file open terminal and use the command `sudo rm /private/var/vm/sleepimage`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. After waking my Macbook Pro from sleep, I found that space had magically diminished to just a few megabytes, even though I had several GB free before putting it to sleep. Deleting the sleepimage as suggested in the above post freed up the space again (the image had grown to about 4GB - pretty much the amount of space I was missing).